# inserting Via Output Parameter C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

I Have a Form which will send Data to Multiple Table on Single Click, 
Person, Education, Experience, Reference.

How can i add Data into Multiple Table so All Have Same Person ID in them,

I am Newbie and using tier Architecture, all the Database code is in DAL,, ) Working with Asp 2.0

I am thinking to doing it with a Stored procedure of Inserting into Person and getting PersonID a output parameter, but i dont know how to use that output Parameter to insert into other Tables.

My Sample COde is This

public virtual bool AddJobApplication(int JobID, string Name, string FatherName, string Phone, string Email, string Address, int AppID)
        {

```
            obj_db2.objCmd.CommandText = "AddApplication";
            obj_db2.objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            obj_db2.objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("JjobID", JobID);
            obj_db2.objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
            obj_db2.objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", FatherName);
            obj_db2.objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email );
            obj_db2.objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Address);
            obj_db2.objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", Phone);
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@AppID", AppID);
            param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            param.ParameterName = "@AppID";
            param.DbType = DbType.Int32;
            obj_db2.objCmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            obj_db2.objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

}

I have this Function in DAL and i am getting param as output Paramter, I know i can access this AddJobApplication from code behind to enter form information, but not getting the point of how to use this output to insert,, Sorry if i am Taking Very Low Level but i need help.

Comment: Can you clarify, please? Are you asking how to get an output parameter from a stored procedure in C#?

Comment: NO ,, i am asking how to use an output parameter to insert into other Tables.

Comment: Please post relevant code of what you have tried, and try to clarify your problem.  Ie, expected behavior vs actual behavior, etc.

Comment: I have plz check i am calling parameters in Data Access Layer but Problem is my out put parameter is in DAL and i am submitting form Data through form code behind, so how can i access output parameter in Front Layer,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That really depends on the architecture that's been established.

If it's easier, you can probably just return the identity of the new record instead of using an output parameter:

```
INSERT INTO Person (
    FirstName,
    LastName
)
VALUES (
    'James',
    'Johnson'
)

SELECT @@IDENTITY --return the identifier of the new record
```

If you're going to be updating multiple tables though, make sure that it's all done in the scope of a single transaction.

Comment: I am using Several Stored procedure for this. One Stored procedure returns me the ID as output Parameter , and then how can i use this ID to Insert into Different Tables ? i want to access this ouput Parameter in the code behind file,,

Answer (score 0):

The stored procedure is the correct way to go about this. With the stored procedure in place you would then define the output parameter in your insert method.

Below is an example of how you might insert a blog post then get back the ID created by SQL.

**Example (inserting a blog post):**

```
 public int InsertArticle(ArticleItem articleitem)
    {
        SqlParameter articleid = new SqlParameter(Parameters.ArticleID, SqlDbType.Int);
        articleid.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(Conn, CommandType.StoredProcedure, INSERT_ARTICLE,
                                  new SqlParameter(Parameters.Body, articleitem.Body),
                                  new SqlParameter(Parameters.Category, articleitem.Category),
                                  new SqlParameter(Parameters.ExpireDate, articleitem.ExpireDate),
                                  new SqlParameter(Parameters.PublishDate, articleitem.PublishDate),
                                  new SqlParameter(Parameters.Published, articleitem.Published),
                                  new SqlParameter(Parameters.Section, articleitem.Section),
                                  new SqlParameter(Parameters.Title, articleitem.Title),
                                  articleid);
        return (int)articleid.Value;
    }
```

Calling the code

```
public void InsertAllTheThings()
{
    var articleId = InsertArticle(articleItem); //Insert an article, return the ID
    //Once you have the id, use it as needed.
    var data = new SomeAwesomeData();
    data.ArticleID = articleId;
    data.IsAwesome = true;
    InsertSomeRelatedData(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but all this output Parameter is in DataAccessLayer, but i want to Access this output Parameter in code behind file of the Form, So i can add into multiple Tables using the output ID, any thoughts??

Comment: As you can see in the code example, it returns the ArticleID. You can then use that ID where ever you need it. If you are working in a multi-tier application, you wouldn't call additional Inserts or Updates from the form, you would do this from the DAL.

Comment: Thanks,, i do get the idea of Inserting via DAL using this output paramter,, but i am getting Form values to add into Databse, its like UI->BLL->DAL,,i am confused and newbie but i need your expert help.